# AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content exclusive to Honeycomb 3.1 - 3.2.1

Tags: android, exception, oncreate, android-actionbar-compat

After last update my app has the following issue:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.package/my.package.MyMainActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1818)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:214)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateHC.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateHC.java:38)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
at my.package.MyBaseActivity.onCreate(MyBaseActivity.java:68)
at my.package.MyApiServiceActivity.onCreate(MyApiServiceActivity.java:51)
at my.package.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:88)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
... 11 more
```

However, I'm never calling `requestWindowFeature` or similar. There are no dialogues involved either. The report itself comes from BugSense, I never had this problem myself. It's a fairly popular app and the issue is **exclusive** to Android **Honeycomb**: 3.2, 3.2.1 and 3.1. It didn't happen in previous version of the app. The only change in `onCreate` function since the update is the fact I switched from `ActionBarSherlock` to `ActionBarCompat`.

Anyone spotted this issue as well and/or has any ideas how to overcome the problem?

**EDIT:**
I am adding the link to [the source for `ActionBarActivityDelegateHC`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/android-4.3_r3.1/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivityDelegateHC.java) from v7 package where the crash stack trace (Caused by...) starts. There the requestFeature call happens, but it's called correctly, even before `super.onCreate`.

I use Gradle to import the package: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'`

Comment: the same issue during rotation, I suppose to fix it by locking orientation on honeycomb devices. there is too sad statistics for honeycomb: http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform , so we won't care about it )

Comment: @shomeser Do you know if this issue specific to rotation?

Comment: I reproduce it only during rotation, so I will lock landscape orientation on honeycomb, but if you find any suitable solution, I'll use it

Comment: I got this crash if when i used setHasOptionsMenu(true); in fragment onCreate()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So looks like solution from @shomeser (comments to the question) is a way to go for the time being.

There are two ways to compromise:

- If you don't have different layouts for landscape and portrait, you can disable the orientation changes (in AndroidManifest: `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"`)
- If you have some handling on orientation change and can't use "configChanges", you can lock the orientation (in `onCreate`)

```
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
            || Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    {
        this.setRequestedOrientation( ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

- and finally my least favourite (Posting this for completion though), drop ABC and go back to ABS.

I also posted a [ticket on Android Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60841), but it being a Honeycomb issue, I don't expect getting an answer.

**UPDATE:** After releasing app with locked orientation for specific Honeycomb devices, I still see this crash being reported, though less frequent.

**UPDATE 2:** 
**Issue was fixed!** Now just wait for the release of new support lib: [google issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60841)

Comment: do you have stacktrace of crash, is it the same as first one? and did you test your application on real device?

Comment: @shomeser it's the same stack trace - it crashes on activities that have locked orientation; the bug report points to real devices (always the same Honeycomb versions).

Comment: give me a link to your application, please. I think you can reproduce it after pause and resume.

Comment: Same happens on HONEYCOMB (API 11). I suggest you edit the `IF` for `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)` .

Comment: @tdevaux thanks! I corrected response with your suggestions. Now let's hope the new release of support package will appear soon to fix this issue permanently.